# Possible to output field data of same value in vtk with element's index range?

Tags: vtk, legacy, paraview

In paraview's legacy vtk file, is it possible to output element's type or field data of same value, with range of element index? In this way, we can avoid to store duplicated data and save a lot of storage space.

For example, I have a simulation of many particles, need to output each particle's velocity at the center of mass. In vtk file, same velocity has to be written to all particle's surface points, which is super redundant in my option. Also, as the surface mesh is composed of triangles no other type, I would like to do:

```
CELL_TYPES N_Tri
5 1 N_Tri  # means cell type is of the same from cell-1 to cell_N
```

instead of writing N_Tri '5' in the vtk file, is there any similar way to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

There is not <strike>exactly</strike> this feature natively.

<strike>What I suggest here is to create more cells in your dataset. You can create [polyvertex](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyVertex.html#details) cells, each grouping N points sharing the same value. Then you may create a CellData Array with the corresponding value.</strike>

#### Edit

Previous tip will not work as intendend as you still are required to provide data for triangle strip cells ...

So if you really want to save some disk space, the solution may be to look  at Field Data, as it allows you to store some array of custom size, and to implement your own logic.

The drawback is that VTK will not be able to interpret it for Filtering or Coloring natively, so you may need to create a special filter to port the FieldData to the corresponding Cells/Points for later computation. But the file will be lighter.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It would involve a lot of work. I am not familiar with paraview/vtk's source code. If there is any thing similar we can do in the new XML format? No time for coding at the moment.

Comment: Both Legacy and XML format reflect the VTK data model. So they provide same kind of feature (XML will not help you more for your pb). Note that it is highly recommended to use VTK to write the XML files instead of trying to do so manually

Comment: Aha, so there is available solution for now. I will try to find solutions if someone already did this.